# Как определить окончание обновления адаптера RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Имеется ExpandableView на основе RecyclerView. Когда я разворачиваю группу, до в адаптер добавляется некоторое количество элементов. Если последний добавленный элемент в RecyclerView становится невидимым, то хочу прокрутить список до этого элемента. Все необходимые данные есть, получаю их в RecyclerView.onScrolled, но проблема в том, что я не могу определить окончания этого процесса, что бы определить, какой элемент будет последним видимым. Т.е. момент нажатия на группу выполняется намного раньше чем список окончательно сформируется. Есть идеи? Спасибо.

Comment: [Этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31854673) на английском SO может Вам помочь?

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов, спасибо за ссылку. Воспользовался другим примером в тех же ответах, вроде получилось, но анимация при сворачивании выглядит отвратительно.